# python OOP functions into classes/method

Tags: python, oop, huffman-code

I am coding a huffman coding tree in python, I have used one class for tree nodes, but I want the whole program to be object oriented. I just cant seem to be able to turn my functions into classes and run the whole thing as OOP. Is it possible to convert functions into classes/methods or does it involve rewriting the entire code in OOP style. The code works ok, im just trying to get my head around OOP and how to implement it. Any help would be great!  Code below.

'''

```
import heapq

class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, freq, char=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.char = char
        self.freq = freq
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

  
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.freq < other.freq

    def isLeaf(self):
        return (self.left == None and self.right == None)

def createTree(freqData):
    huffmanNodes = []
    for char in freqData:
        huffmanNodes.append(TreeNode(freqData[char], char))
    
    heapq.heapify(huffmanNodes)
    while (len(huffmanNodes) > 1):
        # obtain the two minimum-frequency Huffman nodes
        child1 = heapq.heappop(huffmanNodes)
        child2 = heapq.heappop(huffmanNodes)
        parent = TreeNode(child1.freq + child2.freq, left=child1, right=child2)
        heapq.heappush(huffmanNodes, parent)
    return None if huffmanNodes == [] else heapq.heappop(huffmanNodes)


def hTreeToHCode(hTree):

    code = dict()
   
    def getCode(hNode, curCode=""):

        if (hNode == None): return
        if (hNode.left == None and hNode.right == None):
            code[hNode.char] = curCode
        getCode(hNode.left, curCode + "0")
        getCode(hNode.right, curCode + "1")
        if hNode.char == None:
            print("")
        else:
            print('Character = {}  :  Freq = {} --- Encoded into {}'.format(hNode.char, hNode.freq, curCode))

    getCode(hTree)
    return code

def encode(s, freqData):
    hTree = createTree(freqData)
    hCode = hTreeToHCode(hTree)
    hEncoded = ""
    for char in s:
        hEncoded += hCode[char]
    return hEncoded.strip()

def decode(s, freqData):
    hTree = createTree(freqData)
    decodedStr = ""
    curTreeNode = hTree
    for charCode in s:
        if (charCode == "0"):
            curTreeNode = curTreeNode.left
        else:
            curTreeNode = curTreeNode.right
        if (curTreeNode.isLeaf()):
            decodedStr += curTreeNode.char
            curTreeNode = hTree
    return decodedStr

words = "hello welcome to my huffman algorithm code"
charlst = {}
for char in words:
    charlst[char] = charlst.get(char,0) + 1


freqData = charlst
encodedStr = encode(words, freqData)
print("encodedStr", encodedStr)
decodedStr = decode(encodedStr, freqData)
print("decodedStr", decodedStr)
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

you can put function outside the `NodeTree` class in a `Main` class and add a `run` method with var initialisation etc and put at the end of your program a

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    Main.run()
```